# Can't get the ajax jsonp result

Tags: jquery, ajax, cross-domain, jsonp, zepto

I'm performing an Ajax jsonp call on a remote server (crossdomain request) (using Zepto, based on jQuery).
Here is a part of the code I'm using to perform it :

```
$.ajaxJSONP
        ({
            url : "http://www.aramisclub.be/adminzone/swf/boxes_application/ap/userBoxe.php?callback=?",
            success: function(data){
                $("#p2").html("SUCCESS");
            },
            error: function(){
                $("#p3").html("ERROR");
            },
            complete: function(){
                $("#p4").html("COMPLETE");
            }
        });
```

When I look at the network log (in opera dragonfly) I can clearly see the call returning from the remote server. The content of the page is there too.
But the request doesn't trigger any of the cases (success, error, complete).

And when looking at the javascript console, here's what I get :

```
Syntax error at line 1 while loading: expected expression, got '<'
<link href="lib/css/
^
```

Does anyone know why I can't get anything from the ajax call(back) while the HTTP request does end up with a 200 status code.

Comment: That link is not returning JSON.  That appears to be the fundamental problem.

Comment: @ExplosionPills `JSONP`*

Comment: @Blazemonger unless you use the jquery jsonp plugin, though even that is buggy at times.